# BooleanToVisibilityConverter to collapse/show a TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

In **MainWindow.xaml** I have the following...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>

// Tab control

<TabItem x:Name="DebugTab" Header="Debug" Visibility="{Binding Path=DebugTabState, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibility}}">
    // Some content
</TabItem>
```

In **MainWindow.xaml.cs** I have the following...

```
public bool DebugTabState
{
    get
    {
        return AppData.EnableDebuggingCheckBox;
    }
}
```

In **DebugSettings.xaml** I have the following...

```
<CheckBox x:Name="EnableDebuggingCheckBox" Content="Enable Debugging" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnableDebugging}" />
```

In **DebugSettings.xaml.cs** I have the following...

```
public bool EnableDebugging
{
    get
    {
        return AppData.EnableDebuggingCheckBox;
    }
    set
    {
        AppData.EnableDebuggingCheckBox = value;
    }
}
```

And finally, in **AppData.cs** I have the following...

```
private bool _enableDebuggingCheckBox;

public bool EnableDebuggingCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        return _enableDebuggingCheckBox;
    }
    set
    {
        _enableDebuggingCheckBox = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EnableDebuggingCheckBox");
    }
}
```

Checking and unchecking EnableDebuggingCheckBox updates the value to true or false, as expected, but the DebugTab isn't hiding or showing. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no OnPropertyChanged notification from MainWindow.DebugTabState

Comment: Somewhere you have `local:DebugSettings` and then an additional property in the view? Why not binding directly to that control (just give it an `x:Name`): `Visibility="{Binding DebugTabState, ElementName=debugSettings, ...}` ? I recommend you to look into MVVM earlier, it will help you to design better UI.

Comment: @Sinatr - The checkbox is in a usercontrol separate from MainWindow where I need to hide/show the tab. My thought was that updating a public variable that holds the last state of the checkbox and implements INotifyPropertyChanged would resolve the issue.

Comment: Sure, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the class holding `DebugTabState`, then subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of class with `EnableDebuggingCheckBox` to rise notification for `DebugTabState`, but this is silly.

Answer (score 0):

If Appdata is a public property in MainWindow, change the binding to:

```
<TabItem x:Name="DebugTab" Header="Debug" Visibility="{Binding Path=AppData.EnableDebuggingCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibility}}">
    // Some content
</TabItem>
```

You can then remove MainWindow.DebugTabState.

Alternatively, in MainWindow advise to INotifyPropertyChange from AppData and raise an PropertyChanged event if EnableDebuggingCheckBox changed

Comment: I tried using AppData.EnableDebuggingCheckBox but that didn't work, and I'm not sure why. And I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the second suggestion. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You may look for binding errors using Snoop (https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf))